# JTabbedPane NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, nullpointerexception, jtabbedpane

I create a JTabbedPane in a JFrame using netbeans visual creator. And build a JPanel also. When I add that JPanel as a tab I got the following error. Sometimes it doesn't occur.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTabbedPaneUI.paintContentBorder(WindowsTabbedPaneUI.java:145)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.paint(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:791)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5219)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1529)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1452)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5167)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4978)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

This is the code to add JPanel as a Tab.

```
 jTabbedPane2.addTab("Swimmer",new SwimmerPanel());
```

What is the error?

Comment: its look like jTabbedPane2 is still null try initialize and check

Comment: Right now, this question should be closed (one as a duplicate and two for no runnable code). Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't initialized the JTabbedPane :

```
JTabbedPane jTabbedPane2 = new JTabbedPane();
```